# extract text between href tag notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this html page:

```
<div class="abc">
<a href="www...." title="aaaaa">TEXTONE</a>
</div>

<div class="abc">
<a href="www...." title="bbbb">TEXTTWO</a>
</div>
```

Only the div class are the same, I need to extract TEXTONE and TEXTTWO. How can I do with find function?
Thank you

Comment: You could write a Python parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is matching all text in `<a..>` tags that are inside `<div class="abc">`, with or without spaces or linebreaks.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<div class="abc">\s+<a [^>]+>\K.+?(?=</a>)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Find next</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<div class="abc">   # literally
\s+                 # 1 or more spaces
<a [^>]+>           # <a...> tag
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
.+?                 # 1 or more any character, included newlines
(?=</a>)            # positive lookahead, make sure we have and tag after
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this would be to use a parser, but if you want quick and dirty regex to use in Find in Notepad++...

Try the following regex:

```
\w+(?=<\/a>)            # match all [A-Za-z0-9_] before </a>
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aPOvlR/2)

**If the text may contain spaces, you can use the following regex:**

```
(?<=>).+(?=<\/a>)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aPOvlR/3)

[image]

Comment: The trick is cool, it's just that the text can have spaces - generally speaking.

Comment: @virolino Thank you for comment, added another regex to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that maybe you have some other elements, and probably you want to find/replace, which if that'd be the case, some expression similar to:

```
(<div class="abc">\s*<a\s+[^>]*>)(.+?)(<\/a>)
```

might work and your desired output is in `$2`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OSO0hM/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OSO0hM/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/OSO0hM/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

An improvement of vs97s regex would be:`([\s\S])*?<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>([\s\S])*?`
with `\2\n` as replacement!

Explanation:

`([\s\S])*?` takes anything until the next pattern match, ungreedy

`<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>` takes an `<a[...]>TEXT</a>` tag and saves the text

`([\s\S])*?` ehm...see above! ;-)

If you replace it by `\2\n` the second match, which is the text of the a-tag, will be placed there, followed by a newline, instead of the tag.

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)*?` it is very ineficient.

Comment: I don't think that it really matters in an HTML-file, but thanks for the advice. Is there a wildcard that matches really everything?

Comment: Just `.` with `/s` modifier, or `[\s\S]`